# Telling rm command to exclude a subfolder named 'graphs'

Tags: linux, command-line, git

I'm quite ignorant when it comes to linux commands. I found this line in a post-receive setting in my git production hook.

```
find /home/app/myapp.com/app/tmp/cache -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

Inside that /app/tmp/cache folder is a bunch of other subfolders as follow:

```
models/
views/
persistent/
graphs/
```

Now, I want that command to exclude the `graphs/` subfolder, but not sure how to rewrite that command.

Could anyone help?

Comment: That `find` command will not feed any directory to the `rm` command, due to the `-type f` parameter, which practically tells `find` to only touch files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
find  /home/app/myapp.com/app/tmp/cache \( -name graphs -prune \) -o -type f -delete
```

where

- `\( -name graphs -prune \)` tells find to skip graphs
- `-o -type f -delete` or else, delete files.